# Phusion Passenger Not Logging

Tags: apache, logging, passenger

I've been having problems getting Passenger up and running on my Ubuntu 10.04 box (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9243272/passenger-ruby-on-rails-issues).

I've finally got it working, but now logging doesn't work.  `logs/production.log` only sporadically gets notifications (and they come in chunks), and `/var/log/apache2/error.log` only logs cache misses.

I've set `PassengerLogLevel` to 2, but still am not getting much information in the Apache error log.

What did I do wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it's a reported issue in Rails 3.2.x

https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/4277

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution is that the Passenger-process has no writing rights to your log-directory. If it cannot open these files for writing, you will start seeing log-messages in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

At least it was like this in our case.